# jQuery: Why can't I access the event object in my scroll event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to access the original event object but the object returns undefined..

```
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
        alert(event.pageX);
    });
```

I'm just trying this out if it will work. The example is as basic as possible so I can work out other events too.

Comment: Change both instances of 'event' to 'e'...

Answer (score 7):

One thing to be careful is **not to use the word `event`** as a name of a parameter (or a variable) because in some browsers (like IE and Chrome), `event` is already an object, and if you use it you will be overwritten the already existing function.

Thus, try changing your code to this :

```
$(window).scroll(function(ev) {
    alert(ev.pageX);
});
```